# Dynamic type instance creation

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, types, casting

I have a problem using dynamic types to instantiate a custom class.
Example, I have the following class:

```
public class myClass<T>
{
    public myClass(String header);
}
```

If I use the following code, everything works fine:

```
var myInstance = new myClass<int>("myHeader");
```

However, I am in a position I don't have the `int` type defined, so I need to dynamically cast it from a generic type parameter. What I tried so far:

1.

```
    Type myType = typeof(int);
    var myInstance = new myClass<myType>("myHeader");
```

2.

```
    int myInt = 0;
    Type myType = myInt.GetType();
    var myInstance = new myClass<myType>("myHeader");
```

In all examples I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'myType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The reasons I cannot use `int` directly is because I am loading the types from specific assemblies at runtime, so they will not be "int" at all times.

Comment: Can you make the function generic and just do `new myClass<T>("myHeader");`?

Comment: Thanks Quantic, this helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

For creating `generic` lists on the runtime, you *have-to* use [**Reflection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int myInt = 0;
Type myType = myInt.GetType();

// make a type of generic list, with the type in myType variable
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);

// init a new generic list
IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

**Update 1:**

```
int myInt = 0;
Type myType = myInt.GetType(); 
Type genericClass = typeof(MyClass<>); 
Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(myType); 
String MyParameter = "value"; 
dynamic MyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass, MyParameter);
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, as a complement, below the full code:
int myInt = 0;
Type myType = myInt.GetType();
Type genericClass = typeof(MyClass<>);
Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(myType);
String MyParameter = "value";
dynamic MyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass, MyParameter);

Regards

Comment: @m506 You're welcome.  Don't forget to accept the  answer if was what you were looking for. I updated the post and put your code there.